# Why is `GetFormat` called twice?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an `IFormatProvider` that logs out what type it's passed:

```csharp
internal class LoggingFormatProvider : IFormatProvider
{
    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        WriteLine($"  formatType: {formatType.FullName}");
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I call this with this code:

```csharp
var myLoggingProvider = new LoggingFormatProvider();
string.Format(myLoggingProvider, "123: {0}", 123);
```

It outputs two calls to the `GetFormat` method:

```
formatType: System.ICustomFormatter
formatType: System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo
```

Why are there two calls?

*I'm generally getting very confused by what calls what with what when it comes to the formatting types.*

Comment: You are missing a step, you also need to provide an implementation of ICustomFormatter whose Format() method gets the actual job done.  It is asking you to provide it but you decided not to give it one.  So it keeps looking, falling back to the standard provider.  I would guess that you *also* want your  LoggingFormatProvider class to implement ICustomFormatter.  You'll then simply return *this* from GetFormat().

Comment: @HansPassant Does returning `null` mean _try again with the default_?

Comment: Roughly, yes.  It doesn't make all that much sense to return null when you indicated that you want to provide a custom formatter.  But if you don't want it to be custom for some reason then you can agree to the standard formatter.

Comment: @HansPassant Is it strange that `123.ToString(myLoggingProvider)` only makes one call (with `NumberFormatInfo`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke `string.Format(myLoggingProvider, "123: {0}", 123)`, .NET is first asking your instance of `LoggingFormatProvider` if it can provide a custom formatter (that is, an instance of `ICustomFormatter`). Since it can't (you are returning `null`), and the value to be formatted is a number, then it fallbacks to requesting you an instance of [NumberFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo(v=vs.110)).

If your parameter was an instance of `DateTime`, you would get a request for an instance of [DateTimeFormatInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. Numbers and dates are apparently the only types of parameters for which you will get this kind of fallback, as [the documentation for IFormatProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) seems to suggest.

Comment: I would like to add that from the source code https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,2c3b4c2e7c43f5a4 specifically from line 1440 we can see that it is used the default formatter in case the type is an IFormattable and the custom provider can't provide a formatter for the specified type

Comment: I wondered if it was some default magic like that.  Thanks for confirming it.